# Webrtc video streaming working properly in localhost but not working in production (using google turn server)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtp, stun, coturn

In local server, video streaming is running proper on both ends but while network changed video of one peer is not going to display to other peer.

I am using google stun server for connection of peer with another network, but then video streaming of one user is not visible
here is my code

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here.I am novice in webrtc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
{#######  variable Initialization #######}
<script>
    let webSocket;
    let mapPeers = {};
    let username = 'user_{{ request.user.id }}';
</script>

<script>

    const iceConfiguration = {
    iceServers: [
        {
            urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
        }
        ]
    }

    function webSocketOnMessage(event){

        let parsedData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(parsedData);
        let peerUserName = parsedData['peer'];
        let action = parsedData['action'];
        console.log(parsedData);
        if(username === peerUserName){
            return;
        }

        let receiver_channel_name = parsedData['message']['receiver_channel_name'];

        if(action === 'new-peer'){
            if (!(peerUserName in mapPeers)){
                createOfferer(peerUserName, receiver_channel_name);
                return;
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (!(peerUserName in mapPeers)){
                        createOfferer(peerUserName, receiver_channel_name);
                        return
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        if(action === 'new-offer'){
            let offer = parsedData['message']['sdp'];
            createAnswerer(offer, peerUserName, receiver_channel_name);
            return;
        }

        if(action === 'new-answer'){
            let answer = parsedData['message']['sdp'];
            let peer  = mapPeers[peerUserName][0];

            peer.setRemoteDescription(answer);
            return;
        }

        if(action === 'video-on'){
            manageVideoEl('on', peerUserName)
            return;
        }

        if(action === 'video-off'){
            manageVideoEl('off', peerUserName)
            return;
        }
    }
</script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    let loc = window.location;
    let wsStart = 'ws://';

    if(loc.protocol === 'https:'){
        wsStart = 'wss://';
    }

    let endPoint = wsStart + loc.host + '/ws/video/meet/'+ '{{ group_name }}/';

    webSocket = new WebSocket(endPoint);
    webSocket.addEventListener('open', (e)=>{
        sendSignal('new-peer', {'receiver_channel_name': '{{ group_name }}'});

    });
    webSocket.addEventListener('message', webSocketOnMessage);
    webSocket.addEventListener('close', (e)=>{
    });
    webSocket.addEventListener('error', (e)=>{
    });

    {% if is_group_creator %}
        sendNotificationOnMessage();
    {% endif %}
});


let localStream = new MediaStream();

    const constraints = {
        'video': true,
        'audio': true
    }

    const localVideo = document.querySelector('#local-video');

    const btnToggleAudio = document.querySelector('#btn-toggle-audio');
    const btnToggleVideo = document.querySelector('#btn-toggle-video');



    let userMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(stream => {

            localStream = stream;
            localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
            localVideo.muted = true;


            let audioTracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
            let videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();

            audioTracks[0].enabled = true;
            videoTracks[0].enabled = true;

            btnToggleAudio.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                audioTracks[0].enabled = !audioTracks[0].enabled;

                if(audioTracks[0].enabled){
                    btnToggleAudio.classList.replace('mic-off', 'mic-on')
                    return;
                }
                btnToggleAudio.classList.replace('mic-on','mic-off');
            });

            btnToggleVideo.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                videoTracks[0].enabled = !videoTracks[0].enabled;

                if(videoTracks[0].enabled){
                    btnToggleVideo.classList.replace('camera-off','camera-on');
                    sendSignal('video-on', {})
                    localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
                    return;
                }
                sendSignal('video-off', {})
                localVideo.srcObject = null;
                btnToggleVideo.classList.replace('camera-on','camera-off');
            });
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            {#console.log('Error accessing media devices', error);#}
        });

</script>


<script>

    function sendSignal(action, message){
        console.log("Sending message to other end");
        let jsonStr = JSON.stringify({
        'peer': username,
        'action': action,
        'message': message
        });
        console.log(jsonStr);
        webSocket.send(jsonStr);
    }

    function createOfferer(peerUserName, receiver_channel_name){
        console.log("creating offer");

        let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);
        addLocalTracks(peer);
        peer.addEventListener("icegatheringstatechange", ev => {
  switch(peer.iceGatheringState) {
    case "new":
      console.log("gathering is either just starting or has been reset");
      break;
    case "gathering":
      console.log("gathering has begun or is ongoing");
      break;
    case "complete":
      console.log("gathering has ended");
      break;
  }
});
        peer.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event)=>{

           if(event.candidate){
               console.log('new ice candidate', JSON.stringify(peer.localDescription));
               return;
           }
           sendSignal('new-offer', {
               'sdp':peer.localDescription,
               'receiver_channel_name': receiver_channel_name
           });
           // to notify video status of other users when new users join
           if(!localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled){
               sendSignal('video-off', {})
           }

        });


        let dc = peer.createDataChannel('channel');
        dc.addEventListener('open', ()=>{
            console.log("dc connection opened");
        });
        dc.addEventListener('message', dcOnMessage);
        console.log("Creating video");
        let remoteVideo = createVideo(peerUserName);
        console.log("video created, setting track");
        setOnTrack(peer, remoteVideo);
        console.log("track setted");
        mapPeers[peerUserName] = [peer, dc];

        peer.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', ()=>{
           let iceconnectionState = peer.iceConnectionState;

           if(iceconnectionState === 'failed' || iceconnectionState === 'disconnected' || iceconnectionState === 'closed'){
               delete mapPeers[peerUserName];

               if(iceconnectionState !== 'closed'){
                   peer.close();
               }

               removeVideo(remoteVideo);
           }
        });



        peer.createOffer()
            .then(o => peer.setLocalDescription(o))
            .then(() => {
                {#console.log("local description set successfully");#}
            });


    }


    function createAnswerer(offer, peerUserName, receiver_channel_name){
        let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);

        addLocalTracks(peer);
        let remoteVideo = createVideo(peerUserName);

        setOnTrack(peer, remoteVideo);
        peer.addEventListener('datachannel', e=>{
           peer.dc = e.channel;
            peer.dc.addEventListener('open', ()=>{
                {#console.log("dc connection opened");#}
            });
            peer.dc.addEventListener('message', dcOnMessage);
            mapPeers[peerUserName] = [peer, peer.dc];

        });

        peer.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', ()=>{
           let iceconnectionState = peer.iceConnectionState;

           if(iceconnectionState === 'failed' || iceconnectionState === 'disconnected' || iceconnectionState === 'closed'){
               delete mapPeers[peerUserName];

               if(iceconnectionState !== 'closed'){
                   peer.close();
               }

               removeVideo(remoteVideo);
           }
        });

        peer.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event)=>{
           if(event.candidate){
               {#console.log('new ice candidate', JSON.stringify(peer.localDescription));#}

               return;
           }
           sendSignal('new-answer', {
               'sdp':peer.localDescription,
               'receiver_channel_name': receiver_channel_name
           });
        });

        peer.setRemoteDescription(offer)
        .then(() => {
            {#console.log('Remote description set successfully for %s', peerUserName);#}

            return peer.createAnswer();
        })
        .then(a => {
            {#console.log('Answer created');#}

            peer.setLocalDescription(a);
        })
    }

    function addLocalTracks(peer){
        localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
            peer.addTrack(track, localStream);
        });
        return;
    }


    function  createVideo(peerUserName){
        userId = peerUserName.split('_')[1]

        // Video element Creation
        let remoteVideo = document.createElement('video');
        remoteVideo.id = peerUserName + '-video';
        remoteVideo.autoplay = true;
        remoteVideo.playsInline = true;
        remoteVideo.classList.add('custom-video');
        remoteVideo.setAttribute('data-id', userId);
        addVideoToDOM(remoteVideo, userId)

        return remoteVideo;
    }

    function addVideoToDOM(video, userId){
        let videoContainer = document.querySelector('#video-container');
        $.getJSON(`/chat/call/participant/${userId}`, function(data){
            // Styling Elements
            video.style.backgroundImage = `url('${data.profile_image_url}')` // if video off then show this bg
            let nameTag = document.createElement('span');
            nameTag.classList.add('name-tag');
            nameTag.innerText = data.username;
            let participantActionsEl =  document.createElement('div');
            participantActionsEl.classList.add('participant-actions');
            let videoParticipantEl = document.createElement('div');
            videoParticipantEl.classList.add('video-participant');
            videoParticipantEl.appendChild(participantActionsEl);
            videoParticipantEl.appendChild(nameTag);
            videoParticipantEl.appendChild(video);
            videoParticipantEl.setAttribute('data-delete', 'true') // For removing element
            videoParticipantEl.setAttribute('data-id', userId) // For showing feature
            videoContainer.appendChild(videoParticipantEl);
            addMemberToList(data)
        })
    }

   

    function manageVideoEl(status, peerUserName) {
        const userId = peerUserName.split('_')[1]
        // After element in DOM update video element
        setTimeout(() => {
            let videoEl = document.querySelector(`video[data-id="${userId}"]`)
            if (videoEl !== null){
                // Saving source
                if (mapPeers[peerUserName]){
                    if (videoEl.srcObject != null){
                        mapPeers[peerUserName][2] = videoEl.srcObject;
                    }

                    if (status==='on'){
                        videoEl.srcObject = mapPeers[peerUserName][2] || null;
                    } else if (status==='off'){
                        videoEl.srcObject = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    function setOnTrack(peer, remoteVideo){
        let remoteStream = new MediaStream();
        remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
        peer.addEventListener('track', async (event)=>{
            console.log(remoteStream);
           remoteStream.addTrack(event.track, remoteStream);
        });
    }

    function removeVideo(video){
        removeMemberFromList(video.dataset.id)
        video.closest(`[data-delete='true']`).remove()
    }

</script>



{######### script to talk with group consumer #######}
<script>
    let group_chatSocket_chat;
    let receiver_group = "{{group.id }}";
{% if is_call_starter and send_notifications %}
    function sendNotificationOnMessage()
    {

        group_chatSocket_chat = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
            'ws://' + window.location.host +
            '/ws/chat/group/' + "{{ group.name }}" + '/'+ "{{ request.user.id }}" +'/');

        group_chatSocket_chat.onopen = function(e){
            {#console.log("Connection open");#}
            let url = `${location.protocol + '//' + location.host}/chat/video/{{ join_url }}`;
            group_chatSocket_chat.send(JSON.stringify({
                            'message': `New Video call is started! Join Now Link: ${url}`,
                            'receiver_id': receiver_group,
                            'command': 'new_message',
                            'bucket_id': 0,
                        }));
        }


    }
{% endif %}


</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you move out side of the network the webrtc ICE candidate gathering process may fail because of Routers NAT and firewalls therefore you must have a turn server in your configuration that will relay the traffic if the direct p2p connection establishment fails

Comment: Thank you for your response but i already used google stun server and also added it in object

let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);

Comment: stuns server is only used to get you public ip it won't help you to traverse nat and firewall you will need a turn server for that . seems that you don't have clear understanding of webrtc you can watch this video to get more clear picture of why you application is failing on server https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FExZvpVvYxA

Answer (score 0):

I think your network firewall not support STUN ( udp hole punching )
so you have to add turn server address to your iceConfiguration.

you can get turn server address https://www.twilio.com/stun-turn